# SpamAssassin spam analyzer script in PHP based on sa-learn command

Tags: php, bash, perl

I wrote a small script to analyse spam messages that are spam *false negative*; meaning that they are spam messages in nature but that happened to be in your *INBOX* folder because your spam filter failed to detect it correctly (I personally use SpamAssassin and unfortunately it rarely happens).

The goal is to have a chance to analyse spam messages that are put in spam folder manually by running a script in cron jobs.

Obviously, all spam messages will be analysed regardless of which email client you're using (*Thunderbird, Kaiten Mail or Roundcube*), because all you need is to have a message moved in spam folder.

Example of my well working *PHP script*:

```
<?php
// Check if there is messages in SPAM folder that don't have [SPAM] lable (e.g.: manually moved from INBOX)
exec("grep -L '\[SPAM\]' /home/domainexample.ru/Maildir/.Junk/cur/* 2> /dev/null", $spam_messages);

if (!empty($spam_messages)) {

    $sa_learn = '/usr/bin/sa-learn --spam';
    foreach ($spam_messages as $spam_message) {
        //Learn a message that we believe is spam
        $sa_learn .= ' ' . $spam_message;
        $marked_as_spam = file_get_contents($spam_message);
        // Adding [SPAM] flag to message's subject of analyzed message
        $marked_as_spam = str_replace("Subject:", "Subject: [SPAM] ", $marked_as_spam);
        file_put_contents($spam_message, utf8_encode($marked_as_spam));
    }
    // Logging the results
    $sa_learn .= ' > ' . '/home/domainexample.ru/.spamassassin/logs/' . date('d.m.Y-G:i') . '_analyzer.log';
    //Executing analyzer in background 
    shell_exec("nohup $sa_learn 2> /dev/null & echo $!");
    // Cleaning cached messages in Dovecot
    shell_exec("rm -f /var/lib/dovecot/index/domainexample.ru/.Junk/*");
}
?>
```

I would like to have (in case there are) few ideas for improving this already working **PHP** script but most importantly, I would like to learn of how to write the same script using **PERL** or/and **BASH** scripting.

Could you please suggest some ideas for improving current *PHP* script, along with providing pure and fully working examples of the same scenarios in *PERL* or/and *BASH*?

Comment: Interesting script, but it's a bit of a tall order to do all of these things. If you focus on either a single language (and show us the code if it's not PHP), you probably have a better chance at getting an answer. Judging by the use of `exec` and `shell_exec` it should be easy to convert this to a Bash script.

Comment: It wouldn't be that easy for me to do it, as I'm not familiar with Perl, for instance. If I do it, it will take much time for me and only few minutes for an expert in either Bash or Perl. I have just proposed to provide any example Bash `or/and` Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an *untested* Bash version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset

while IFS= read -r -u 9 path
do
    /usr/bin/sa-learn --spam "$path" \
        > "/home/domainexample.ru/.spamassassin/logs/$(date +%d.%m.%Y-%G:%S)_analyzer.log" \
        2>&1 &
    sed -i -e 's/^Subject:/Subject: [SPAM] /' "$path"
    rm "$path"
done 9< <(grep -FL '[SPAM]' /home/domainexample.ru/Maildir/.Junk/cur/* 2> /dev/null)
```

Some changes from the original:

- Uses `grep`'s `-F` option to speed up search.
- Runs `sa-learn` repeatedly instead of once to avoid having to accumulate the data. Shouldn't slow down the execution since the processes are backgrounded.
- Deletes files as soon as they are processed, to avoid reprocessing if the previous run failed.

Comment: Based on the logic above, it's so different from PHP and I don't see how the `$path` is created / looped. Your example unfortunately is not working. I checked it on the test server and nothing is happening - logs are not created, messages are not processed, clean up is not deleting anything. What is wrong?

Comment: As logs are empty, I can't tell what is going on there. The script execution I just hanging.. Until you click `CTRL+C`

Comment: Yes. It print's out everything in console.

Comment: Yes, correct, logs are created every-time and it's just empty..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9208/discussion-between-l0b0-and-ilia-rostovtsev)

Comment: Why have you deleted all of your comments? You make me feel I'm talking to myself? :D

Comment: Any ideas why your script is not working (hanging) and why logs are empty but instead it's reported to the console? Should be easy to fix? ;)

Comment: You *are* expected to do some investigation yourself.

Comment: Alright, will do that! My point was to get a working example just the same way I wrote it in PHP. I'm not very well familiar with BASH / Perl and it will take more time for me. Thanks anyway..